How to reference fields from different database1.collection1 to database2.collection in mongo db aggregation?
I have tried using lookup option to join 2 different collections under SAME database & that works. But is it possible to join fields from 2 different databases.collection in mongo db aggregation ? If not what's the way to connect them in Grafana ?
I tried using database.collection in lookup field but seems it just accepts collection name.
